# Why does Ruby have zip and transpose when they do the same thing?

Tags: ruby, arrays, zip, transpose

They seem to do the same thing.

```
g = [{ a: "A" }, { b: "B" }]
r = [{ x: "X" }, { y: "Y" }]

g.zip(r)        # => [[{:a=>"A"}, {:x=>"X"}], [{:b=>"B"}, {:y=>"Y"}]]
[g,r].transpose # => [[{:a=>"A"}, {:x=>"X"}], [{:b=>"B"}, {:y=>"Y"}]]
```

Why have both methods?

Comment: They do the same thing on *those particular inputs*.

Comment: Per what @ColonelPanic says, you can't draw the conclusion that they're the same when you are only looking at a trivial example. It's a bit like asking why Ruby has both `*` and `+` since `2+2` and `2*2` do the same thing.

Comment: @mbratch Thanks for making me feel stupid. Well put! :D

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton haha not intended. I'm just prodding a little more exploration on your part. :) One major characteristic of Ruby is that when you want to do something, there are often several different ways to do it that can achieve the same result. Some ways are more "canonical" or semantically appropriate than others.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`#transpose`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) *Assumes that self is **an array** of arrays and transposes the rows and columns.*

[`#zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) assumes `self` can be any [`Enumerable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html) object.

More differences are here

```
a = [12,11,21]
b = [1,2]

[a,b].transpose # transpose': element size differs (2 should be 3) (IndexError)
a.zip(b) # => [[12, 1], [11, 2], [21, nil]]
b.zip(a) # => [[1, 12], [2, 11]]
```

That to apply the `#transpose` method `a` and `b` should be of the same size. But for applying `#zip`, it is not needed `b` to be of the same size of `a`, ie `b` and `a` can be of any of size.

With `#zip`, the resultant *array* size will always be the size of `self`. With `#transpose` the resulting *array* size will be any of the inner array's size of `self`.