# How can I transpose different sized ruby arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays, transpose

I have an array:

```
arr=[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]],
```

I have the following code:

```
arr.transpose
```

but it doesn't work,how to solve it?

I am getting

```
 [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]].transpose
IndexError: element size differs (2 should be 3)
    from (irb):13:in `transpose'
    from (irb):13
    from /home/durrant
```

my solution:

```
arr.reduce(&:zip).map(&:flatten)
```

output:

```
[[1, 4, 6], [2, 5, nil], [3, nil, nil]]
```

Comment: What is the expected result for the given array?

Comment: Look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455310/why-does-ruby-have-zip-and-transpose-when-they-do-the-same-thing to understand why #transpose didn't work.

Comment: The answer, though I can't post as such is that the number of elements have to be the same for this operation.

Comment: So, if you have [[1,2,3],[4,5,0],[6,0,0]].transpose
 => [[1, 4, 6], [2, 5, 0], [3, 0, 0]] 
 that works because the number of elements in each array is the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A similar answer was posted (but deleted) an hour earlier:

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]

arr[0].zip(*arr[1..-1])
#=> [[1, 4, 6], [2, 5, nil], [3, nil, nil]]
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
[1, 2, 3].zip([4, 5], [6])
```

This approach assumes that your first sub-array is always the longest. Otherwise the result will be truncated:

```
arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]

arr[0].zip(*arr[1..-1])
#=> [[1, 3, 6], [2, 4, nil]]  missing: [nil, 5, nil]
```

Comment: I was looking for a safe transpose method, and used your solution. It only seems to work when the first array is bigger than all the other ones. Using it with `arr.reverse` returns `[[6, 4, 1]]` instead of `[[6, 4, 1], [nil, 5, 2], [nil, nil, 3]]`.

Comment: @EricDuminil that's correct, I've update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 13):

Using [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) as in Stefan's answer is the most straightforward, but if you insist on using [`transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose), then:

```
l = arr.map(&:length).max
arr.map{|e| e.values_at(0...l)}.transpose
# => [[1, 4, 6], [2, 5, nil], [3, nil, nil]]
```

Or without using either:

```
Array.new(arr.map(&:length).max){|i| arr.map{|e| e[i]}}
# => [[1, 4, 6], [2, 5, nil], [3, nil, nil]]
```

Comment: This is the best solution for a safe-transpose. Using `zip` only works when the first array is bigger than the others.

Comment: Very nice. I suggest you limit your answer to #2 and merely state that it does not depend on the first subarray being the largest.

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the subarrays don’t match, an IndexError is raised.

```
irb(main):002:0> arr=[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]]
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
irb(main):003:0> arr.transpose
IndexError: element size differs (2 should be 3)
    from (irb):3:in `transpose'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/liuxingqi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

should be:

```
irb(main):004:0> arr=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
irb(main):005:0> arr.transpose
=> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

or

```
irb(main):006:0> arr=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
irb(main):007:0> arr.transpose
=> [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: How did you able to _answer_ while question is closed... _Strange!!_

Comment: Yeah funny, I'm curious too.