# Sort array by batches in ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting

Sorry if this has been asked before, I am not sure how to even search for it and what I have searched for doesn't yield any useful answer.

Here is my issue, I have a framework that basically manages the jobs that will be submitted to a PBS cluster and each job will need to read from an input file. We are in a case in which we have more than 5k jobs that need to run and there are batches of, lets say, ~30 that read from different files but the rest of them read from a file which is being read by another job.

This could be easily dealt with (although not the best solution buy maybe the quickest one for the timescale we have) by being able to sort the job list by the ID which basically means which file it is going to be reading from, i.e. I would like to sort an array like this

```
a = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]
```

into

```
a = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
```

Is there a way of achieving such an ordering in ruby? I could think of an algorithm buy maybe it has already been done and someone knows the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: `a.group_by(&:itself).values.transpose.flatten` works for your example but not for the example provided by tadman.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution

Thanks to @sagarpandya82 for the original idea and @Cary Swoveland for bug finding!

Either use 2 methods :

```
def safe_transpose_and_flatten(array)
  l = array.map(&:length).max
  array.map{|e| e.values_at(0...l)}.transpose.flatten.compact
end

def sort_by_batches(array)
  safe_transpose_and_flatten(array.sort.group_by{|i| i}.values)
end
```

Or this one-liner (split over multiple lines for relative readability) :

```
def sort_by_batches(array)
  array.group_by{|i| i }.values                  # Chunks of equal values,
       .sort_by{|v| -v.size }                    # sorted by decreasing length,
       .reduce(&:zip)                            # transposed,
       .map{|r| r.flatten.compact.sort }.flatten # flattened and sorted
end
```

## Example

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
sort_by_batches(a) # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]

a = [1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 1, 1]
sort_by_batches(a) # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3]

a = [1,2,2,3,3,3]
sort_by_batches(a) # => [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3]
```

## Steps

Here are the steps for the second array :

```
[1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 1, 1] # input
{1=>[1, 1, 1, 1], 3=>[3, 3, 3, 3], 2=>[2, 2, 2], 4=>[4, 4, 4], 5=>[5]} # group_by
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [4, 4, 4], [5]] # values
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [4, 4, 4], [5]] # sort_by -length
[[[[[1, 3], 2], 4], 5], [[[[1, 3], 2], 4], nil], [[[[1, 3], 2], 4], nil], [[[[1, 3], nil], nil], nil]] # zip
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3]] # map(&:flatten) and compact
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3] # flatten
```

`.reduce(&:zip).map(&:flatten).compact` was used at first as a supposedly safe transpose, but it didn't work when the first array was smaller than the others.

The first method use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26017880/6419007) answer for transposing, the one-liner sorts the arrays by decreasing length before using `zip`.

## Application to Job class

Here's a very basic Job class as an example :

```
class Job
  attr_reader :id
  def initialize(id)
    @id = id
  end

  def self.sort_by_batches(jobs)
    safe_transpose_and_flatten(jobs.sort_by{|j| j.id}.group_by{|j| j.id}.values)
  end

  def to_s
    "Job %d" % id
  end
end

jobs = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4].map{|i| Job.new(i)}
Job.sort_by_batches(jobs)
```

It outputs :

```
Job 1
Job 2
Job 3
Job 4
Job 1
Job 2
Job 3
Job 4
Job 1
Job 2
Job 3
Job 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful explanation, I will take a look as soon as I can!

Comment: Very polite way to say that the code is wrong ;). Thanks.

Comment: It's OK to format one-liners over multiple lines, so readers don't have to scroll horizontally to read it. It still counts as a one-liner. btw, I'm always mystified by the announcement, "Here's a one-liner", followed by a single line of code. ("steps" should have been "stems" in my earlier comment.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Totally right, but I need to sleep from time to time :). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been able to try it until today, was travelling to give a seminar these days. It works great! Now lets see if this fixes the performance issue but that's for another matter :)

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with a collation function:

```
def collate(input)
  # Split the input array up into chunks of identical values
  # and sort the resulting groups.
  sets = input.group_by { |v| v }.values.sort_by(&:first)

  # Recombine these into a single output array by iterating over
  # each set and transposing values. Any nil values are scrubbed
  # with compact.
  (0...sets.map(&:length).max).flat_map do |i|
    sets.map do |s|
      s[i]
    end
  end.compact
end
```

You can see this work on some less trivial data:

```
input = [1,1,3,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,1,1]

collate(input)
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3]
```

Here `5` only shows up once.

Comment: Thanks! I imagine it will work perfectly but I have to test it. It is not as trivial as an array of numbers since the ID is an instance variable of the job but I imagine that doing 
`input.group_by { |v| v.ID }`
should work the same, right?

Comment: Good one! After realizing that I had initially misunderstood the question, I did some editing and came up with what amounts to a variation of your answer.

Comment: @JuanpeAraque Basically, yes. You can define any grouping mechanism you want, but you'll also want to define a comparator on each of those objects so the `sort_by` call works correctly. You can do this by [defining `<=>` which returns 0, 1 or -1](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Comparable.html) depending on sort order. If you `include Comparable` then a bunch of other methods get added automatically based on that one method.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah, I tend to "trust no-one" when it comes to specifications like this and always try to expect the worst.

Answer (score 4):

**Code**

```
def doit(a)    
  b = a.sort.slice_when { |x,y| x != y }
  b.max_by(&:size).size.times.flat_map { |i| b.each_with_object([]) { |c,arr|
    arr << c[i] unless c[i].nil? } } 
end
```

**Example**

```
doit [5, 1, 7, 2, 3, 3, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4]
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 5, 3]
```

**Explanation**

For the example the steps are as follows.

```
a = [5, 1, 7, 2, 3, 3, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4]

c = a.sort
  #=> [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7] 
b = c.slice_when { |x,y| x != y }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fb8a99d94c8>:each>
```

We can see the elements that are generated by the enumerator `b` (and passed to the block) by converting it to an array:

```
b.to_a
  #=> [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4], [5, 5], [7]]
```

Continuing,

```
c = b.max_by(&:size)
  #=> [3, 3, 3] 
d = c.size
  #=> 3 
e = d.times
  #=> #<Enumerator: 3:times>
e.to_a
  #=> [0, 1, 2] 
e.flat_map { |i| b.each_with_object([]) { |c,arr| arr << c[i] unless c[i].nil? } }
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 5, 3]
```

Here is the last operation with some included `puts` statements.

```
3.times.flat_map do |i|
  puts "i=#{i}"
  b.each_with_object([]) do |c,arr|
    puts "  c=#{c}, c[#{i}]=#{c[i]}, arr=#{arr}"
    arr << c[i] unless c[i].nil?
    puts "  arr after arr << c[#{i}]=#{arr}" unless c[i].nil? 
  end
end
```

```
# i=0
#   c=[1, 1], c[0]=1, arr=[]
#     arr after arr << c[0]=[1]
#   c=[2, 2], c[0]=2, arr=[1]
#     arr after arr << c[0]=[1, 2]
#   c=[3, 3, 3], c[0]=3, arr=[1, 2]
#     arr after arr << c[0]=[1, 2, 3]
#   c=[4], c[0]=4, arr=[1, 2, 3]
#     arr after arr << c[0]=[1, 2, 3, 4]
#   c=[5, 5], c[0]=5, arr=[1, 2, 3, 4]
#     arr after arr << c[0]=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
#   c=[7], c[0]=7, arr=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
#     arr after arr << c[0]=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
# i=1
#   c=[1, 1], c[1]=1, arr=[]
#     arr after arr << c[1]=[1]
#   c=[2, 2], c[1]=2, arr=[1]
#     arr after arr << c[1]=[1, 2]
#   c=[3, 3, 3], c[1]=3, arr=[1, 2]
#     arr after arr << c[1]=[1, 2, 3]
#   c=[4], c[1]=, arr=[1, 2, 3]
#   c=[5, 5], c[1]=5, arr=[1, 2, 3]
#     arr after arr << c[1]=[1, 2, 3, 5]
#   c=[7], c[1]=, arr=[1, 2, 3, 5]
# i=2
#   c=[1, 1], c[2]=, arr=[]
#   c=[2, 2], c[2]=, arr=[]
#   c=[3, 3, 3], c[2]=3, arr=[]
#     arr after arr << c[2]=[3]
#   c=[4], c[2]=, arr=[3]
#   c=[5, 5], c[2]=, arr=[3]
#   c=[7], c[2]=, arr=[3]
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 5, 3]
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't feel like coming up with many variable names for my example, so I used : `(p (p (p (p (p (p (p array).sort).group_by{|i| i}).values).reduce(&:zip)).flatten).compact)` :D

Comment: Avoiding local variables is generally a good thing, but here I haven't figured out how to do that without making the code overly complex. :-DD