# Trouble transposing the array which has different size

Tags: ruby

I have an array like this

```
[["ContactCreate", "PolicyCreate"], ["Page_1", "Page_3"], ["Page_2"]]
```

I want to transpose this array, But If I transpose this array, this says

```
Uncaught exception: element size differs (1 should be 2)
```

Now I have array with various sizes like this, Is there anyway I can fill fill `nil` in the size of the greater array and then I can transpose ? Like

```
[["ContactCreate", "PolicyCreate"], ["Page_1", "Page_3"], ["Page_2",nil]]
```

If

```
 [["ContactCreate", "PolicyCreate","contactCreate], ["Page_1", "Page_3"], ["Page_2"]]
```

then it has to be

```
 [["ContactCreate", "PolicyCreate","contactCreate], ["Page_1", "Page_3",nil], ["Page_2",nil,nil]]
```

Comment: Maybe you can equeue `nil` to small elements before. Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016632/how-can-i-transpose-different-sized-ruby-arrays

Comment: @iGian That perfectly answers my question, once you have this reply, I will delete my question. Thanks.

Comment: The linked question assumes the subarrays are ordered largest to smallest. If that is not necessarily the case you could do the following.  n = arr.map(&:size).max; arr.map { |a| Array.new( n) { |i| a[i] } }.transpose #=> [["ContactCreate",  "Page_1",  "Page_2"], ["PolicyCreate", "Page_3", nil]]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland No, it works for all the cases, for an example, look a this one,here second array is bigger, it works and gave the right result `[["ContactCreate", "Page_1", "Page_2", nil], ["PolicyCreate", "Page_3", "Page_4", "Page_5"]]`

Comment: The two arrays in your example both have four elements. If `arr = [["Page_2"], ["ContactCreate", "PolicyCreate"], ["Page_1", "Page_3"]]`, @Stefan's (accepted) answer at that link yields `arr[0].zip(*arr[1..-1])
#=> [["Page_2", "ContactCreate", "Page_1"]]`.

Comment: I missed @sawa's (excellent) answer to the earlier question, which does not rely on the ordering by size of the subarrays.  So yes, sawa has answered your question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Stefan's answer works fine for me.

Comment: That's fine, as long as you understand that it requires the first subarray to be the largest subarray.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I am saying first Sub Array need not to be the largest array. It still works fine.

Comment: I showed in my comment above that begins "The two arrays..." that @Stefan's answer only works when the first subarray is the largest. In fact, he makes that clear in his answer.